# Balls with and without replacement

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to teach myself certain topics in this field. I came across this question and wanted to know if it was correct.

> A bag contains $2$ red, $3$ green, and $4$ black balls. If five balls are drawn in succession, with replacement after each draw, what is the probability of getting $2$ red, $2$ green, and $1$ black ball?

My answer:

$\frac{5!}{2!*2!*1!}(2/9)^2(3/9)^2(4/9)$

=$.0731$

> What if it was drawing without replacement?

My answer:

$\binom{2}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{1}/ \binom{9}{5}$

$=.0952$

Can someone please tell me if this is correct? Is there other ways of thinking about this?

Comment: I have not checked the arithmetic. There are missing parentheses in the first answer. The (implicit) reasoning that was used is correct.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the no replacement, presumably the $2! * 2! *1!$ should have parentheses around them to be in the denominator.  The $4/9$ should not be squared.  But I agree with your final numeric answer.  The without replacement is fine.

Comment: Thank you!. Some of it were typo errors.